Why does a Laser Welder or Cutter require different coolant temperatures for the Laser Source and Optics?
I recently purchased a laser welder and found that the chiller has two temperature set-points; one for the optics and one for the laser source. Any ideas on why this is the case? To me it seems that as long as the coolant is above the ambient dew point (so you don't get condensation), having them at the same temperature would be fine, but maybe I am missing something?
